# Simple Window WinAPI Object-oriented

Tags: c++, oop, winapi, window

I try to fire up the simplest window in object-oriented way:

main.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "WinApp.h"


WinApp* p_app;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpszArgument,
    int nFunsterStill)
{
    MSG message;


    if (hPrevInstance == NULL)
        if (!p_app->InitApp(hThisInstance))
            return 0;

    if (!p_app->InitInst(lpszArgument, nFunsterStill))
        return 0;


    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }

    return (int)(message.wParam);

}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

WinApp.cpp:

```
#include "WinApp.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
const char szClassName[] = "WindowsApp";


WinApp::WinApp()
{
}

WinApp::~WinApp()
{
}

BOOL WinApp::InitApp(HINSTANCE hThisInstance)
{

    WNDCLASSEX wincl;

    HINSTANCE m_hInstance = hThisInstance;

    wincl.hInstance = m_hInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;

  if (!RegisterClassEx(&wincl))
  return FALSE;

  return TRUE;

}

BOOL WinApp::InitInst(LPSTR lpszArgument, int nFunsterStill)
{

     m_hwnd =   CreateWindowEx(
                0,
                szClassName,
                "Windows App",
                WS_OVERLAPPED,
                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                544,
                375,
                HWND_DESKTOP,
                NULL,
                m_hInstance,
                NULL);

    ::ShowWindow(m_hwnd, nFunsterStill);
    ::UpdateWindow(m_hwnd);

    return TRUE;

}
```

WinApp.h:

```
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

class WinApp
{
public:

    WinApp();
    ~WinApp();

    BOOL InitApp(HINSTANCE hThisInstance);
    BOOL InitInst(LPSTR lpszArgument, int nFunsterStill);


    HWND m_hwnd;
    HWND h_edit1;
    HINSTANCE m_hInstance;

};
```

I receive an error message:

"Unhandled exception at 0x013F1ADA in _WinApi.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008."

And the yellow arrow point to the definition of the "m_hwnd" handler.

Comment: `p_app` appears to be uninitialised.

Comment: The Windows API is object oriented already. What are you trying to improve?

Comment: @IInspectable is Windows API object oriented already, since when?. you are maybe talking about those frameworks and c++ classes, maybe java. all of them are just encapsulating  flat Windows API.

Comment: @milevyo: The Windows API has been object oriented since it's inception, decades ago. It implements objects, referenced through opaque handles, data encapsulation, and polymorphism. All of these can be implemented using C, which the Windows API incidentally does.

Comment: from wikipedia:  Windows NT is a family of operating systems (including Windows 7, 8, Phone 8, Xbox) produced by Microsoft, the first version of which was released in July 1993. It is a high-level-language-based, processor-independent, multiprocessing, multi-user operating system. It is best described as object-based rather than object-oriented as it does not include the full inheritance properties of object-oriented languages.

Comment: @milevyo: Inheritance is **one** way to model specialization. COM supports full inheritance in a way you are familiar with. Control subclassing is another solution to the same problem: Inheriting common functionality and augmenting it. A custom window procedure in conjunction with `DefWindowProc`/`CallWindowProc` is essentially the same as virtual methods in a C++ class. If you disagree with the assessment, point out specifics where you believe, the Windows API is not object oriented. Merely saying that it isn't because it isn't doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alan Stokes wrote you have to initialise the pointer:

```
p_app = new WinApp;
```

or

```
p_app = new WinApp();
```

Another thing, in function:

```
BOOL WinApp::InitApp(HINSTANCE hThisInstance)
```

you're creating new temporary variable:

```
HINSTANCE m_hInstance = hThisInstance;
```

and allocating memory to it rather than your member variable (m_hInstance). Try:

```
m_hInstance = hThisInstance;
```